# Azure VM server url not resolving after re-boot

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have an azure VM that I had shut down for a day and have restarted today. After restarting, I can only navigate to that address using the ip address and not using the URL (eg. servername.cloudapp.net).

I was definitely able to access the VM using the URL before I shut down. I also notice that my VM now has a new IP address.

My question is this likely to be some sort of DNS resolution problem? Do I just need to wait a couple of hours for the DNS servers to update?

I plan to turn this server off (it's a test server) when not in use so if it is a DNS resolution problem, are there any settings I should set in Azure so the DNS can refresh faster?

Comment: Hmm, the Azure dns normally updates very quickly. Are guy and to check from a different machine, preferably on a different network to see if there is some local caching going on?

Comment: @Frans : I've tried on both my phone and my PC and I still can't access the server using the url

Comment: I can only say that is very unusual, no idea why it is happening, sorry.

Comment: @Frans : yeah its very puzzling - i even created another new VM and the DNS address for that one worked straight away. I can only say that the problem occurs if I have a VM, I shut it down for a period of time until it changes IP Addresses and then I boot it back up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush the DNS cache in your machine. This is definitely a problem in your end, not Azure. Here's a guide for different operating systems.

[How To Clear Your DNS Cache](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+To+Clear+Your+DNS+Cache)

Regarding the IP change, it will happen most of the times you shutdown/start your VMs since the public and private addresses are not reserved. If you need to fix the IP for your VM cloud service, check this guide:

[Reserved Public IP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690120.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Set a Static Internal IP Address for a VM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn630228.aspx)

UPDATE: Another possible reason is the DNS cache of your internet provider. It could take hours to update. If the problem happens again try checking what is the ip returning from your provider dns server using this nslookup command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup myhost.cloudapp.net
```

Comment: I've tried doing the clear cache thing and it doesn't help. I really think it's the VM and not my own machine because I've tried accessing it on my phone too and only the IP address works

Comment: Is your phone connected to wifi within the same network or using 3g/4g?

Comment: I used the Wi-Fi. Wasn't getting any phone reception. Looks like the DNS works now. Guess it must take time for the change in IP address to propagate

Comment: Most likely if it wasn't your computer it was your internet provider. They also operates on cache and some of them have high TTL for DNS entries which means it could take hours to update to the new ip. Glad it's working now :)